# How does 1ML measure the availability ranking of nodes?

Tags: lightning-network, full-node

If there is an 1ML Node Rank ranking explanation anywhere ? 
My node is online 99.9% but "Availability" dropped down from 700 to 4000 in last 3 months. :( 
I guess this is somehow associated with the number of channels ?

Comment: Could you post a link to that node on 1ml? though questions like those are hard to answer as it is not public how 1ml measures this data

Comment: Hello Rene, thank you for attention. 
here is my node

https://1ml.com/node/02bfb576be997eac8afbf6fb22e8e69b58eaea2640f6aab6b7ba3f54ca5adf49f4

Yep, 1ml have not shed light on this question, and we haven`t sources to check by self, but probably there is any 1ML dev we can ask to know for sure?

I sent same question to https://twitter.com/LNstats recently, but looks like this account is driven by bot (some script), and maybe even not related to 1ml.

Comment: Sorry that does not make sense. My node has an availability of ~400 and was offline several times. Sometimes even for days. Are you positive your uptime  is 99.9%?

Comment: I sure uptime is 99.9. I connect to this node from my Zeus LN mobile wallet everyday, to check if node is online.
Also I use this node for generating receipts on OC store, to show demo of LN payment gateway for opencart.

now I made uptimerobot.com page, to collect 100% reliable uptime.
https://stats.uptimerobot.com/QOMOOIyjq

Comment: This node have only 3 channels, and only few (up to 5) connections with other nodes, probably that's why availability is low. 

I mean node could be unavailable for others often, but still online .

I had an issue, when user from California was not able to connect to my node, but node was online. And issue was solved, after my connection to his node.

And maybe it's becaue of low time-out limit and high latency between Ukraine and USA :), so I need to make more local channels.

What do you think ?

Comment: So, as we can see, node has 100% uptime during last 7 days.
but availability drop from 4070 to 4311

Comment: Availability  4752 now

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is found.
I didn`t forwarded 9735 port on router, as LND and my router support UPnP.
But looks like UPnP works not as intended, so sometimes host was accessible on 9735 port, and most of the time not :(.

Now I forwarded 9735 port to my Raspberry Node local address , so  Availability on 1ML not dropping down.